# String compare in array

Tags: php

In my array, I want to compare `"JUDGE OF APPEAL"` keyword and if found,it should print the all record related to JUDGE OF APPEAL.Please note that I have not defined my array manually.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Chief Justice Sundaresh Menon
    [1] => JUDGE ANDREW PHANG BOON LEONG
    [2] => JUDICIAL COMMISSIONER HOO SHEAU PENG
    [3] => JUDGE OF APPEAL JUDITH PRAKASH
    [4] => JUDGE OF APPEAL TAY YONG KWANG
)
```

My expected result is this:

```
[3] => JUDGE OF APPEAL JUDITH PRAKASH
[4] => JUDGE OF APPEAL TAY YONG KWANG
```

Comment: and what have you **tried** so far yourself? SO is *not* a free coding service, you know? without showing any effort whatsoever, your question is clearly off-topic (and people are encouraged *not* to answer it).

Answer (score 0):

try this below code :

```
<?php
$temp = array(
    '0' => 'Chief Justice Sundaresh Menon',
    '1' => 'JUDGE ANDREW PHANG BOON LEONG',
    '2' => 'JUDICIAL COMMISSIONER HOO SHEAU PENG',
    '3' => 'JUDGE OF APPEAL JUDITH PRAKASH',
    '4' => 'JUDGE OF APPEAL TAY YONG KWANG');

     foreach($temp as $k=>$value){
        if (preg_match("/(JUDGE OF APPEAL)/i", $value)) {
            echo $value."<br>"  ;
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae28e4aee264a1ea26048681719b0e89ad19b72a

```
  $array = [
    'Chief Justice Sundaresh Menon',
    'JUDGE ANDREW PHANG BOON LEONG',
    'JUDICIAL COMMISSIONER HOO SHEAU PENG',
    'JUDGE OF APPEAL JUDITH PRAKASH',
    'JUDGE OF APPEAL TAY YONG KWANG'
  ];

  print_r(array_filter($array, function($s) { return (strpos( $s, 'JUDGE OF APPEAL' ) !== false); }));
```